# Change value of property depending another in class

Tags: c#

I have a class named ValidationsResult with this properties:

```
public class ValidationsResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }        

    public string[] Errors { get; set; }

    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        Errors.Append(error);
    }
}
```

But I want that the property IsValid to be read only, and depending if the object has Errors or not modify that property automatically.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you used properties that _don't_ use the `{get;set;}` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public class ValidationsResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get => Errors != null && Errors.Length == 0; }  // no errors = valid      

    public string[] Errors { get; set; }

    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        Errors.Append(error);
    }
}
```

That will make it `readonly` and it will tell you if you have errors

Based on the comment, yes. Better if you designed it in the following fashion.

```cs
public class ValidationsResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get => Errors.Count == 0; }  // or !Errors.Any()      

    public List<string> Errors { get; } = new List<string>();

    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        Errors.Add(error);
    }
}
```

You initialize the errors but outside consumer can still use it. Hence - next evolution

```cs
public class ValidationsResult
{
    private List<string> _errors  = new List<string>(); // private member

    public bool IsValid { get => _errors.Count == 0; }  // or !Errors.Any()      

    public string[] Errors { get => _errors.ToArray(); }

    public void AddError(string error)
    {
        _errors.Add(error);
    }
}
```

Now you encapsulating your error collection not letting consumer to modify it directly, but via `AddError`

Comment: Good point about the null check. (note to OP) you should make sure you're initializing `Errors` before attempting to use it in `AddErrors`, and ensure you're using the Nullable Reference Types feature.

Comment: I also would suggested to not use a fixed length datastructure but instead a list for example.

Comment: @Fildor I added suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As an answer is already posted and accepted, I just want to point to a different thing.

- Never implement this type of mechanism in a class! Keep classes as simple as possible.
- Please use classes as POCOs, and implement this type of logic in a different layer of the application (e.g. Business Logic layer).

Otherwise, over time, your application will become complex and convoluted and hence hard to maintain.